# Neural networks: avoid bias in any direction for output

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm having difficulties with the CartPole problem.

The input to the Cart takes either `0 or 1` as input; Either move left or right.

Lets say we have a net with `4 inputs` plus `bias`, `3 hidden layers` with `1 neuron` each and `1 output`; where
all weights are randomized `floats` between `0 and 1`, and the inputs will also be randomized `floats` between `-10 and 10`.

Because i chose everything random, I inherently expect the output to be approximately `0.5` on average, and that the cart will go as much right as it goes left.

This is not the case; i approximately get `0.63` on average. This leads to big problems, because the cart never decides to go to the left. **This seems to be dependent on the amounts of neurons per hidden layer.**

```py
class NeuralNetwork(object):
  def __init__(self):
     self.inputLayerSize = 4
     self.hiddenLayerCount = 3
     self.hiddenLayerSize = 1
     self.outputLayerSize = 1

     #Initialize weights
     self.W = []
     self.W.append(np.random.rand(self.inputLayerSize + 1, self.hiddenLayerSize))
     for _ in range(self.hiddenLayerCount - 1):
        self.W.append( np.random.rand(self.hiddenLayerSize, self.hiddenLayerSize))
     self.W.append( np.random.rand(self.hiddenLayerSize, self.outputLayerSize))

  def forward(self, data):                                                                     
     layers = []
     data = np.append(data, [1])   #ADD BIAS                                                        
     layers.append(data)
     for h in range(self.hiddenLayerCount + 1):                                                
         z = np.dot( layers[h], self.W[h] )                                                     
         a = sigmoid(z)                                                                         
         layers.append(a)

     return sigmoid( layers[self.hiddenLayerCount + 1] )
```

I fix the problem by subtracting the `output` with `0.1`, but this is obviously cheating; I see no mathematical reason to use `0.1` as some sort of magic number.

I believe I'm approaching the problem wrong, or got some of my code messed up. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "all weights are randomized floats between 0 and 1" -- to avoid biasing in any direction I believe they should have been randomized between  -1 and 1.

Comment: @qwertyman Although this helps, it is not quite what i was looking for. the average `0.63` turns to `0.61`, but it is still not `0.5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's at least one problem with your neural network that skews your result probabilities: the model output is the `sigmoid` of the last layer which itself is a `sigmoid`.

This means that your logit (i.e., the raw score) is in `[0, 1]`, so the final probability is computed on a `[0, 1]` range, not `[-inf, inf]`.

[image: sigmoid]

As you can see from the graph above, this makes the results probability to 
be greater than 0.5.

**Solution**: try the same network without the last `sigmoid`.